# How to convert image coordinates to UTM coordinates in Python

Tags: gdal, qgis, utm

I labeled a part of a GeoTiff image with polygon using an annotation software which output is X,Y image coordinates (including sub-pixel ones) for each point in the polygon in XML format.

The question is how to convert these points to UTM coordinates in Python in **GeoJson** format.

From the GeoTiff image, I can extract the following information:

```sh
    gdalinfo -mm test-area.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: test-area.tif
Size is 1356, 1351
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 11N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 11N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-117,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World - N hemisphere - 120°W to 114°W - by country"],
        BBOX[0,-120,84,-114]],
    ID["EPSG",32611]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (432390.000000000000000,3727776.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (3.000000000000000,-3.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  432390.000, 3727776.000) (117d43'46.05"W, 33d41'15.97"N)
Lower Left  (  432390.000, 3723723.000) (117d43'44.94"W, 33d39' 4.38"N)
Upper Right (  436458.000, 3727776.000) (117d41' 8.05"W, 33d41'16.87"N)
Lower Right (  436458.000, 3723723.000) (117d41' 7.01"W, 33d39' 5.28"N)
Center      (  434424.000, 3725749.500) (117d42'26.51"W, 33d40'10.63"N)
Band 1 Block=1356x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
    Computed Min/Max=185.000,4470.000
  NoData Value=32767
Band 2 Block=1356x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
    Computed Min/Max=299.000,4895.000
  NoData Value=32767
Band 3 Block=1356x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
    Computed Min/Max=276.000,5419.000
  NoData Value=32767
Band 4 Block=1356x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
    Computed Min/Max=659.000,5466.000
  NoData Value=32767
```